# Using Phabricator for a full code audit

Tags: audit, phabricator

I recently got Phabricator installed and am hoping to use it for our future code reviews. Once issue I'm having is that we have a couple of projects that have never been reviewed/audited, and we're hoping to sit down and audit them.

However, I'm not sure how we can go about doing that using Phabricator. When it comes to auditing, Phabricator seems geared towards auditing individual commits, rather than a full codebase. I liked the ability to browse through the code in Phabricator, highlight sections and comment them (especially since we've got multiple people reviewing the same code, one of which is in a very different timezone), but I can't do that with the regular code viewer.

Is there a way to do a full code audit of an existing project on Phabricator, while still benefitting from the review features they have such as adding comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist in Phabricator. See the following:

- https://secure.phabricator.com/T5744
- https://secure.phabricator.com/T4348

Comment: Thanks what we ended up doing is creating a new repository, copied our source files in and committing all at once. We could then audit that commit.